# How to add background color in opposite direction

Tags: html, css

So I'm making this small project.

There is a CSS box on top, so the box is floating. It's more of a card in the middle of the screen. I can see my background on top and bottom. 
How can I fill a color to the bottom of that css card?

I wanna fill C with black. And I want to do that in the same class as B. I don't wanna create a separate class for C. Is there a way? Is there a way to make `background-color` in opposite direction?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's also not clear what you mean to make `background-color` go the opposite way, as it's solid.

Comment: @Dejan.S what I mean is like. I wanna fill C with black without adding a new class for it. I wanna add the code to fill C with black in the class for B.

Comment: what about using the same class but adding a style attribute on the div?

Comment: @WKara what do you mean? Sorry I'm kinda new to these stuff

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

```
   <style>
        #boxC {
            background-color: black;
        }
    </style> 

    <div class="classB" id="boxC">
        <div>Box C</div>
    </div>
```

or

```
    <div class="classB" style="background-color: black">
        <div>Box C</div>
   </div>
```